# "502 Bad Gateway" error after killing Gunicorn processes

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I pulled my Django project to my server,  run  `ps aux|grep gunicorn` code, and killed all Gunicorn Processes, now I give 502 Bad Gateway error, although I run:

```
/opt/project/bin/gunicorn -c /opt/project/gunicorn_config.py project.wsgi
```

And it runs OK. but no change! What should I do?

Comment: I think you need a bit more info - are you running this behind nginx? What is your config for this? Is gunicorn listening on a port or on a socket?

Comment: If you are using nginx, it usually means Gunicorn is not setup correctly or running, or nginx is not configured to pass a location to the Gunicorn server.